# what happens to the SET of Cmake

Tags: cmake

here is my code of cmake :

```
PROJECT (HELLO)
SET(SRC ./main.c)
MESSAGE(STATUS "This is BINARY dir "${HELLO_BINARY_DIR})
MESSAGE(STATUS "This is SOURCE dir"${HELLO_SOURCE_DIR})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(hello SRC)
```

if I run, what appears in front of me is that:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
  Cannot find source file:

    SRC

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: hello
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "hello".
-- Generating done
```

if I change my code to

```
PROJECT (HELLO)
SET(SRC ./main.c)
MESSAGE(STATUS "This is BINARY dir "${HELLO_BINARY_DIR})
MESSAGE(STATUS "This is SOURCE dir"${HELLO_SOURCE_DIR})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(hello ./main.c)
```

it just works well.
So, what happens to SET? why didn't it work well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(hello ${SRC})
```

Otherwise, cmake just thinks you have a source file named "SRC" leading to that error you see.